# Finding joint density of $(V,W)$ knowing $X,Y$ where $V=X+Y$ and $W=X/Y$.

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be independent R.Vs uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.
Let $V=X+Y$, $W=\frac{X}{Y}$. Find joint distribution of random vector $(V,W)$. Are $V,W$ independent?

So what I've tried is: 
Let $f_X:(0,1) -> \Bbb R $, $f_Y:(0,1) -> \Bbb R$ be density functions of $X,Y$, then $\forall_{t \in (0,1)} f_X(t)=f_Y(t)=1$. Moreover, according to independence the joint density is $f_{(X,Y)}:(0,1)^2 -> \Bbb R$, $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y) = 1 $.

Now, I want to use transformation rule, that is if $g_{(V,W)}$ is joint density function of $(V,W)$, then:
$g_{(V,W)}(z) = f_{(X,Y)}(h^{-1}(z))\cdot|\det(Dh^{-1}(z))|$ (provided that $h\in C^1 $ )

In my example, $h(x,y) = (x+y,\frac{x}{y})$, and from that afer calculations we get $h^{-1}(v,w) = (\frac{vw}{w+1},\frac{v}{w+1})$

Hence:

$ \frac{\partial h^{-1}}{\partial v}(v,w) = (\frac{w}{w+1},\frac{1}{w+1})$, $ \frac{\partial h^{-1}}{\partial w}(v,w) = (\frac{v}{(1+w)^2},\frac{-v}{(1+w)^2})$

And $|\det(Dh^{-1}(v,w))| = \frac{v}{(1+w)^2} $

So that we get $g_{(V,W)}(v,w) = \frac{v}{(1+w)^2} $ (Since $f_{(X,Y)} \equiv 1$)

But now I have a problem. I need to find the range of $V$ and $W$. So I thought that due to $V=X+Y, W=\frac{X}{Y}$, it should follow that $V\in(0,2)$, $W\in(0,\infty)$, but calculating 
$\int_{(0,2)\times(0,\infty)}g_{(V,W)}(v,w)d\lambda_2(v,w) = 2$, so I had to make a mistake somewhere ( I'm pretty sure it occured when I was trying to find the range).

I would be pleased if anyone could help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3758376/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while but I did found your mistake. Your problem is by simply writing $f_{(X,Y)}\equiv1$. Instead, you should take a deeper look what is happening here
$$ 1\neq f_{(X,Y)}(h^{-1}(v,w)) = f_{(X,Y)}\left(\frac{vw}{w+1},\frac{v}{w+1}\right)  $$
This is only $1$ if $0\leq vw/(w+1)\leq 1$ and $0\leq v/(w+1)\leq1$. Since, we know that $V\in[0,2]$ and $W\in(0,\infty)$, we can simplify these equations to
$$ v \leq \min\left\{\frac{w + 1}{w},w+1\right\}=\min\left\{\frac{1}{w}+1,w+1\right\} .$$
For the purpose of this solution, this inequality means that the density is only defined on the area $$\{(v,w):\ 0< w< \infty,\ 0\leq v\leq \min\{1+1/w,1+w\}\}$$
I am fairly confident that if you integrate your density over this area, your calculated density will integrate to $1$. But this is something I leave for you to check.

Comment: Thank you very much, integrates to 1 ;)

Comment: You are welcome! And, nice!